# How to minimize the times a recursive function is called

Tags: c++

So for the following code I am trying to reduce the amount of time the function call itself so that it is more efficient. The purpose of the code is to perform exponentiation using recursion.

```
int expo(const int m, const unsigned int n) 
{   
    funcCallCounter++;  //counts how many times the function is called
    if (n == 0)//base case
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else if (n % 2 == 0)// for even numbers
        return expo(m*m, n / 2);
    else
        return m * expo(m, n - 1);//for odd numbers
}
```

Comment: If you want "efficiency" (as in speed), you should **measure**. Don't try to guess based on theoretical call counts which version of your function is better, because compilers are built for turning correct and readable code into fast machine code through various transformations that can and will change your code significantly (including call counts).

Comment: I see what you mean. The speed of the code is not dependent on how many times the function is called necessarily.

Comment: Correct. Notice in particular how your function is optimized to _never `call` anything_: https://godbolt.org/z/uu2ETh. Both compilers turned your recursive function into a loop of sorts! The moral of the story is, write clear code and let the compiler worry about speed. If you _really_ need every last ounce of speed, then start by measuring the speed of different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is my favourite approach for the recursive expo which will always give less calls than your approach

```
int expo(int a, int n) {

    funcCallCounter++;
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    int r = expo(a, n / 2);
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
       //Even n
        return r * r;
    }
    else {
        // Odd n    
        return a *r*r;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach is to not make the function recursive?  Or is `pow` supposed to be `expo`?

Comment: I also contest the "always give less calls". The OP's version always makes a single recursive call at most. As does your version.

Comment: If I take 5^3 the function calls itself 4 times using my code.

Comment: and 3 using this approach

Comment: Thank you I will run some test on the code you provided.

Comment: @StoryTeller: in odd cases, that version only calls `expo(a, n / 2)` whereas OP calls `expo(m, n-1)` which calls `expo(m*m, n / 2)`.

Comment: Ironically, this version has infinitely more recursive calls in practice than the code in the question (which has none in an optimized build). Compare https://godbolt.org/z/CjHUPF and https://godbolt.org/z/uu2ETh. As they say, [tail recursion is its own reward](https://xkcd.com/1270/). @Jarod42

Answer (score 0):

You could use shifts to make your execution faster.

- `n % 2` can be replaced with `n & 0x01`
- `n / 2^k` can be replaced with `n >> k`

A division is about 20 cycles while a shift is only 1-2 cycles.

However, maybe the compiler see taht by itself and make this optimisation already.

Best

Comment: The compiler almost always performs this optimization.